# Question in the appendixes A of O'Neill book 2

Tags: algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, homotopy-theory, covering-spaces

I'm reading appendixes A of O'Neill's book, "Semi-riemannian geometry" and I don't understand a something.

[image]

Where we use the assumption that $P$ is simply connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption that $P$ is simply connected shows up when you show that that $\tilde{\phi}$ is a well defined continuous function.

Try it out when $\tilde{M} = \mathbb{R}, M = S^1$, and $P = S^1$ where the map $\tilde{M}\rightarrow S^1$ is the usual universal covering, and $P\rightarrow M$ is the identity.

Then the lift of the identity is discontinuous.

Comment: So I have to show that $\tilde{\phi}$ dose not depend on the choose of $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: The part about $\beta$ is ok because if I lift through a point then the lifting is unique. Thus I have only the part about $\alpha.$ P is simply connected thus any path between $p_0$ and $p$ is homotopic with $\alpha$. So I pass the homotopy to $M$ and I lift it, the lifting is unique through $q_0.$ This proves the continuity too. Is this ok?

Comment: Sounds good to me!

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot!